# unicode to ASCII (getting junk value when i try to publish values from database)

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I have models.py
    from **future** import unicode_literals
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from django.db import models 
    from django.utils import timezone
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class some_model(models.Model):
    info=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message=models.TextField()
    time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)

    def __unicode__(self):   
            return self.info
```

I have forms.py:

```
class someForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = some_model
    fields = ('info', 'message',)
```

I have views.py:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = someForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.save()
                    return redirect('some_all')

    else:
            form = chatForm()
    return render(request, 'some_view.html', {'form': form,})
```

Now i have filled massage field with some  regional language . saving this form to mysql database , every thing is fine . I can see my message column regional language saved as it is in mysql database . After when i try to fetch the data from database like ,

```
for i in some_model.objects.filter(info='some thing'):
    i.message
```

I get some junk value like bellow .

u'\u09b9\u0987'
u'\u09b9\u0987'

But if i print those value like :
    for i in some_model.objects.filter(info='some thing'):
        print i.message

I get the correct input . But i cat print out any thing in django to webpages . So what should i do ?

Comment: That's not junk, they're Unicode escape sequences. Did you try encoding them to UTF-8 to put them on your web pages? You should seriously consider using Python 3, it makes working with Unicode a lot easier & less error-prone.

Comment: how to do that , can you tell me

Comment: I don't know Django, but see [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) in the docs. And you should probably read [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Also see [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Is that Bengali, such as হ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see ans is simple .

```
 for i in some_model.objects.filter(info='some thing'):
       i.message[0]
```

This will print out the exact value . Hope this will help you .